# IntelliJ Ultimate Yarn requires nodejs 4 or higher

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04, yarnpkg, nvm

I recenty changed my nodejs version isntalled using nvm (I always used nvm, it was not a new install replacing native node). Yarn is up-to-date and natively install to

But now, when i try to commit (or anything else which use node in intellij like "run"), i get this kind of error

```
16:40   Commit failed with error
        0 file committed, 1 file failed to commit: feat(acl): fsdfsd
        Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.
```

It's like intellij or yarn didn't recognize anymore nodejs...

- yarn 1.22.4
- npm 6.14.6
- node 12.18.3
- nvm 0.35.3
- intellij ultimate 2020.2
- Ubuntu 18.04

Any idea what's happening ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: what OS are you on? Does the issue persist if you start IDEA from terminal?

Comment: Hell, you're true, I forgot one of the most important... I'm on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Does the issue persist if you start IDEA from terminal?

Comment: Nope, you're true, it solves the issue, what the ** ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When being launched from desktop/System menu/Toolbox, IDEA only sees environment variables configured in login shell, but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`). Possible solutions:

- **Workaround 1**: make required variables available in a login shell by moving them to the corresponding shell profile config
- **Workaround 2**: run IDE from a terminal to make it inherit terminal environment

see also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589

Comment: Many thanks !
Workaround 2 worked but it will not be sustainable. So I tried the workaround 1 and it worked well !
Thanks too to learning me that there is a login sheel different from mine... I didn't knew it !

Comment: Any idea how to do this if I'm running on windows, opening a project on WSL Ubuntu?